# How to secure a Log Drain on Cloud Foundry?

Tags: security, cloud-foundry

I have seen that one of the most suggested pattern to manage logs on Cloud Foundry is to use an User Provided Service as a log drain.

However, in PCF documentation, there is no indication on how to secure this service or how to provide authentication information to make sure the client can use this service for logging.

What prevents other malicious applications from using my logging service in case those have the URL to my logging service?

Answer (score 4):

It's not really something that's done from the client side, and it's going to depend on your log service/provider.

There's usually something unique you'd need to provide through the log drain. I believe some services allow you to have a randomly generated hostname where you send logs. The services which use HTTPS for transport seem to require you to put a token in the URL, where the token is a unique UUID that the service provides you.

From the Cloud Foundry side, you would put whatever information the log service/provider gives you into the user provided service. You would protect that by controlling who has access to the org/space where the service is provided and by limiting the roles given to those that do have access.

Aside from that, check with your log service provider to see what additional security measures or filtering measure they provide to prevent someone from sending unwanted logs to your service.